# Why firebase enter the ondatachange in my query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have very simple database

```
TokenAdmin:
---xccsaccxvkkgmcdds :
     ---token: "cxcxzcfsdfdsfdsfs"
     ---uid: "xccsaccxvkkgmcdds"
---hjhbnghtfgdgdgdffg :
     ---token: "vhghtytyryyr"
     ---uid: "hjhbnghtfgdgdgdffg"
```

Now in my code I want to check and execute some code only if it find uid equal to "hjhbnghtfgdgdgdffg" 
Here is my code :

```
 mDatabase.child("TokenAdmin").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(mycurrUser.getUID()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               //say here toast "A"
            } else {
                //toast "B"
            }



        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            // ...

        }


    });
```

Now I run the code with  mycurrUser.getUID() value set to "xxx" which I don't have listed in the database. I expected the code output was toast B, but instead I always get toast A, which in my understanding, it has found the value in the db. How to fix this, where did I do wrong ?

Comment: Edit your answer and add your if condition code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like this:

```
mDatabase.child("TokenAdmin").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(mycurrUser.getUID()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //Toast A
        } else {
            //Toast B
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused why you're using a query to load the user. You seem to store the token under they UID key already, so this would work:

```
mDatabase.child("TokenAdmin").child(mycurrUser.getUID()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            ... user exists
        } else {
            ... user node does not exist
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```